# Rails: Why do I lose an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've noticed some surprising behavior about foreign keys and losing associations.  I have the following models:

```
class Paper < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :submission
    has_one :author_info
end

class Submission < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :paper
end

class AuthorInfo < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :paper
end
```

In an rspec test, I do this:

```
let(:paper) { FactoryBot.create(:paper) }
```

and my FactoryBot factory does this:

```
factory :paper do
    < sets fields >
    after(:create) do |paper|
        paper.submission = FactoryBot.create(:submission)
        paper.author_info = FactoryBot.create(:author_info)
    end
end
```

When I inspect these objects in a console, I can do `paper.submission` and `paper.author_info` to retrieve the models I expect.  For example, `paper.submission_id` is 2 and `paper.submission.id` is also 2.

**Question 1:**

My understanding is that, when I call `paper.submission`, Rails looks up all rows in the submissions table with an id of `paper.submission_id`.  So I'd expect this:

```
paper.submission_id = 1234
```

not to cause this, since I haven't saved to the DB:

```
paper.submission # nil
```

Why does this cause the association to get lost?

**Question 2:**

Say I've just created the same objects as in Question 1, but haven't modified them (so `paper.id` starts off as 1).  Now I do this:

```
paper.id = 1234
```

I can still do `paper.author_info` and get back the original `author_info`.  This is surprising in light of what happened in Question 1, because `paper.author_info.paper_id` is still 1!  So I'd expect Rails to look up all `Paper`s with with id 1.  In this case, it *does* look like Rails is using the DB to find associations and effectively ignoring the value of foreign keys on unsaved, in-memory objects.

So when is Rails looking up associations by foreign key in the DB vs. actually making use of foreign keys on unsaved, in-memory objects?

Answer (score 2):

To Question 1, we can see what's happening in `rails console`.

```
[10] pry(main)> paper.submission_id = 1234
=> 1234
[11] pry(main)> paper.submission
  Submission Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1234], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
```

Once you change the association's ID, Rails will try to look up that association. This allows you to change the association by ID without first having to go through the expensive of loading an object. If `paper.submission` did not change then `paper.submission.id` and `paper.submission_id` would no longer be synonyms. That would get very confusing.

---

To Question 2...

> ```
> paper.id = 1234
> ```
>
> I can still do paper.author_info and get back the original author_info

This is because of association caching.

It works ***only*** if you've already referred to `paper.author_info`. Then it is cached. Or, in your case, because FactoryBot assigned it as `paper.author_info = FactoryBot.create(:author_info)`. There is no query, it's just an attribute lookup.

If you reload `paper`, change `paper.id` and try `paper.author_info` you will get `nil`. The association will not be cached and it will try to find the AuthorInfo associated with Paper 1234.

```
# paper.reload will not work because the ID is wrong
paper = Paper.find(original_paper_id)
paper.id = 1234
paper.author_info  # nil
  AuthorInfo Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "author_infos".* FROM "author_infos" WHERE "author_infos"."paper_id" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["paper_id", 1234], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful!  Your explanation in #1 makes sense to me; in question #2, you say caching causes us to be able to look up `author_info` even though we've modified `paper.id`.  Why doesn't that same logic apply to question #1: I've also used FactoryBot to assign `paper.submission = FactoryBot.create(:submission)`.  So shouldn't it also be cached and changing `paper.id` shouldn't cause me to lose the `submission` association?  Thanks again!

Comment: @bclayman You'd have to ask the Rails developers to be sure, but here's my educated guess. `belongs_to` works different from `has_many`/`has_one`. `paper.submission_id = 1234` and `paper.submission = Submission.find(1234)` should be equivalent; changing one must change the other. Whereas changing `paper.id` has wide ranging effects. What should it do? Invalidate the associated cache? Change the associated objects to reference the new ID? In the Rails way of doing things, changing the primary key is very rare; I imagine they punted.